# Filter out nodes of an xml tree that have an empty tag, and some elements have line wraps sometimes

Tags: linux, shell, regex, xml, tags

How to get only the nodes that do not have an empty *<sometimes_empty_tag>*?

Taking just a snippet of an xml to play around with, the one to be dropped is the first of the nodes with its empty `<sometimes_empty_tag></sometimes_empty_tag>`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xml>
    <node>
        <sometimes_empty_tag></sometimes_empty_tag>
        <some_other_tag>xyz</some_other_tag>
    </node>
    <node>
        <sometimes_empty_tag>abc</sometimes_empty_tag>
        <some_other_tag>xyz</some_other_tag>
    </node>
    <node>
        <sometimes_empty_tag>abc</sometimes_empty_tag>
        <some_other_tag>mno
# some line wrap1
! some line wrap2
/ some line wrap3
        </some_other_tag>
    </node>
</xml>
```

should become this xml without the first node since that had an empty `<sometimes_empty_tag>`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xml>
    <node>
        <sometimes_empty_tag>abc</sometimes_empty_tag>
        <some_other_tag>xyz</some_other_tag>
    </node>
    <node>
        <sometimes_empty_tag>abc</sometimes_empty_tag>
        <some_other_tag>mno
# some line wrap1
! some line wrap2
/ some line wrap3
        </some_other_tag>
    </node>
</xml>
```

Without line wraps, you could just grep all filled tags and:

- 2 lines below (= -A2) and
- 1 line above (= -B1)

to get each node (and get rid of the "--" of grep afterwards):

```shell
$ grep -E -A2 -B1 "<sometimes_empty_tag>.+</sometimes_empty_tag>" myfile.xml|grep -v -- "^--$" >> myfile_no_empty_sometimesemptytags.xml
```

Yet, there can be line wraps in some elements, and you do not know where and when and how many. Thus, you cannot just take the first x lines before a filled tag and the next y lines after it to be done.

How to filter out nodes of an xml tree that have an empty tag, and some elements have changing line wraps?

Comment: Why don't you use a XML parser? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/372239

Comment: @Toto good hint, I did not know that my question here to fix XML with RegEx was such a running gag on Stack Exchange and the net. I have not thought of an XML parser. And it can surely do it, see [Use XMLStarlet to parse XML in the Linux terminal](https://opensource.com/article/21/7/parse-xml-linux). Could still become an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Don't!?

Do not use RegEx on XML, see the comment which hints at [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/372239) with an answer that shows that this question here is a sort of running gag on the net.

> You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML. *[... long answer following, or perhaps not an answer, but rather a kind of arts]*

Yet, this question is only about tags, not the values, and even if you should not, you still *can* do it with RegEx. Which allows the next two chapters.

*Quick search for a parser for a Linux terminal: [Use XMLStarlet to parse XML in the Linux terminal](https://opensource.com/article/21/7/parse-xml-linux). Whoever wants to show this at work, write an answer. I will not take the time since the workaround of the last chapter is enough for me.*

##### RegEx fix for the unchanged XML (working, but quite some RegEx work)

You can fix this with some positive and negative lookaheads, non-capturing groups, and adding line wraps to the basket of allowed characters. I could find at least the ending `</node>` tag that comes after the node with the `<sometimes_empty_tag></sometimes_empty_tag>`, already quite a long RegEx expression. Yet, I stopped working on this, finding out an easy workaround as follows.

##### RegEx to change the XML before grep (working and easy)

There is an easy workaround. With the help of `sed -E` (see [How to use sed to replace regex capture group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30431410/11154841) for more on how to escape this), replace:

```shell
^(\S.*)[\r|\n|\r\n]
```

with:

```shell
\1linewrapplaceholder
```

This has then replaced any line wrap with "linewrapplaceholder" if it comes after an unindented text that does not start with a space. This replacement also happens to the xml frame at the beginning and at the end, but that does not harm.

Do as in the question, remove all nodes that have the empty *sometimes_empty_tag* in them by means of:

```shell
$ grep -E -A2 -B1 "<sometimes_empty_tag>.+</sometimes_empty_tag>" myfile.xml|grep -v -- "^--$" >> myfile_no_empty_sometimesemptytags.xml
```

In the new file *myfile_no_empty_sometimesemptytags.xml*, replace back the placeholder with the line wrap, that is, replace:

```shell
linewrapplaceholder
```

with:

```shell
\r
```

And you are done without needing an XML parser, just with `sed` and `grep`.

Again, better avoid RegEx on XML. You *can* do it, though. Perhaps your server does not allow you to install a parser and you do not want to copy the large file around? Or you are just fine with a quick workaround against all odds?